# Simulate page break with box-shadows

Tags: css, page-break

I am trying to create a page separation with CSS but I faced an issue with the box-shadow property.

I have a container whitch looks like a black page, and I want to separate it into two pages with a same lookas the end and start of page. Here is an image of what I have (note the gap between the side and bottom shadows):

> [image]
> <sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/20/1400166997-wig.jpg))</sub>

and here is an image of the desired output:

> [image: image2]
> <sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/20/1400166186-excpect2.jpg))</sub>
> .

**Requirements:**

1. I need to get exactly the same on the separation corner.
2. I can't use two containers because I drag & drop items in this one, I can only use one container.
3. The container height is dynamic.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5K4K4/)

*HTML:*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="calPrin" id="barrePage1">
        <div class="calHaut"></div>
        <div class="calBas"></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
body{
    background-color:rgb(186,186,186);
}

.container{
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
    width: 782px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;   
    height:500px;
 
}

.calHaut{
    width: 782px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 1px 1px;
    position: absolute;    
}

.calBas{
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 2px;
    width: 782px;
    border-top: solid black 1px;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.calPrin{
    top:50px;
    background-color: rgb(186,186,186);
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 786px;
    left:8px;
}
```

Comment: why not just make two containers? - http://jsfiddle.net/5K4K4/1/

Comment: I forgot to mention it but i can't use two containers... i drag & drop items here and items are contained in the container.

Comment: you're right about *it's hard to explain*. I don't really understand what the problem is. The image together with the red rectangles mean nothing. Maybe some image showing the result you want should be added.

Comment: I make it right now, sorry for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **simulate a page break** inside your container with box shadows, you can do this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5pVda/)**

output:

[image: simulated pagebreak CSS]

*****EDIT*****

For your use case, you can remove one div and with a bit of tweaking fo the shadows, you can get this :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5pVda/5/)**

---

**Code for the first demo :**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="calPrin"></div>
    <div class="shdw-right"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {
    background-color:rgb(186, 186, 186);
}
.container {
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 782px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #656565;
}
.calPrin {
    position:relative;
    left:-1px;
    width:784px;
    height:50px;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    background-color:rgb(186, 186, 186);
    z-index:1;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 15px 5px -5px #656565;
}
.calPrin:before, .calPrin:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#BABABA;
    z-index:2;
    width:10px;
}
.calPrin:before {
    height:100%;
    right:100%;
    border-right:3px solid #BABABA;
    box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px 0px #BABABA;
}
.calPrin:after {
    left:100%;
    top:20px;
    bottom:0;
    width:15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px 0px #BABABA;
}
.shdw-right {
    position:relative;
    left:100%;
    width:30px;
    top:-31px;
    margin-left:-15px;
    height:20px;
    background:#BABABA;
    box-shadow: 0px -10px 5px 0px #BABABA;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be good with your solution, i not need as many shadows (only like in my exemple). I will try to reduce your values and check if it's ok!

Comment: @Superdrac it is possible to tweak the shadows to be the same as your images, I don't have time to do that right now but I will tomorow, tell me if you manage before, otherwise I'll tweak tomorow.

Comment: @Superdrac I tweaked the shadows and managed to remove one div see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5pVda/5/ if this is what you need, I'll included it in my answer but I'll wait for your feedback first.

Comment: It seems to be perfect ! Thank you really !

Answer (score 2):

There is a beautiful solution using `calc` but looks like `calc` is still not widely supported by old browsers (especially IE browsers). You can use `:before` and `:after` to add pseudo-elements for the `.container` and simply add border, box-shadow and background for those elements instead while the border, background and box-shadow of the container should be removed (the default background is transparent).

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Title goes here</h2>    
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body{
  background-color:rgb(186,186,186);
}
.container {    
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;    
  width: 782px;    
  height:500px;    
  position:relative;      
}
.container:before {
  content:'';    
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}
.container:after {
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 57px); /* 50px of the top and 7px of the divider */
  position:absolute;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  border:1px solid black;       
  background:white;     
}
```

If your container's height is absolute (and fixed) (as in your code, it's `500px`) you can still calculate the value for the `height` of the `:after` yourself (it's `443px`) without using `calc`. However if it's not absolute, this solution won't work.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/5K4K4/8/)

Note that the script I added in the demo is just to show that user can still interact with the actual container. All the `:before` and `:after` are sent to behind.

Finally, you can always use more elements (including real and pseudo-elements) to achieve what you want **but** it's fairly complicated, requires a lot of positioning and layering techniques.

Comment: I can't do this .. In my project, i need to add more than one page intersection, so i can't use the aftore & before properties on the container itself. I absolutely need to add elements to the dom.

Comment: @Superdrac so instead of pseudo-element, for each **virtual** section, you need 1 real element (wrapped in the container), send it to behind, note that the container's background should not be set (default by transparent), also the border and box-shadow should be set on the **virtual** sections instead.

Comment: BTW, **unless** your boss wants you to do it in such an odd way, you should not make things more complicated like that.

Comment: Thank for your advices and for the code explanation ! I check this tomorrow

Comment: Ok so i can't use this because the height is dynamic. I don't have any solution right now...

Answer (score 0):

Your third box-shadow property is the v-shadow, which moves the whole shadow up or down.

The only way to achieve your desired effect with a box-shadow is to apply a box-shadow to a container, and set the v-shadow to 0 but apply padding to the bottom and right of the container.

I'm not sure how being able to drag and drop into this element will be affected by putting it in a container - after all, it is already contained by other DOM elements such as the body.

Answer (score 0):

not too sure of what you look for, but would an `<hr/>` be more adapted ? **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fqhdt)**

With such CSS :

```
body{
  background-color:rgb(186,186,186);
}
.container{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-shadow: 
    1px 1px 1px,
    inset 0 0 0 1px;
  padding:1px;
  width: 782px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;   
  height:500px;
}
hr {
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
  border:none;
  height:8px;
  background-color:rgb(186,186,186);
  margin:0.25em -3px 0.25em -1px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}
hr:before {
  content:'';
  height:0.1px;
  margin:-3px 4px 3px 0px;
  display:block;
  box-shadow:2px 0px 1px 1px  black;
  background:white;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I will look at it, the most difficult is to reproduce the exact same shadow effect..

I also need to be able to set the up and bottom part of separation in case of I only have one page.

Comment: @Superdrac to increase similiraty, you may patch hr with a pseudo element. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HFvkq , for the rest , i still do not get it "if only one page" ? Is this for a print purpose ?

Comment: Just for a display purpose but there is more than one page.. And the height of the container is calculate dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you are trying to get? http://jsfiddle.net/mHn29/2/

```
<div class="pane">one</div>
<div class="pane">two</div>
```

css

```
body{
    background-color:rgb(186,186,186);
}

.pane{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-width: 2px 4px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

Comment: No exactly, look at my first fiddle and at the image.

Comment: I did, in chrome, and it was totally broken - not sure what you were trying to do. If you want a visual divider, why not split the html up semantically and style each of them rather than creating two divider divs that are semantically meaningless ... or am I getting the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: I replaced the jsfiddle link. I can't physically split my container, it must stay virtual.

Answer (score 0):

There's two difficulties going on here:

1. The box-shadow is larger than the element, not just shifted to the right. This is solved by the spread-radius option in box-shadow. See [box-shadow on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).
2. The box-shadow looks to be blurred except for on the top side of the element. This can be solved by covering up the top shadow with a pseudo-element... this is an odd design choice, but I left it in my example anyway to see how you might do it.

Pen with an example of spread-radius and covering up box-shadow's top blur with a pseudo-element: http://codepen.io/tholex/pen/uobEA